# Setting Style properties via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am setting some properties via CSS like so:

`:root {--foo: #4c3552;}`

I wonder if I can do the same via JS. I have tried:

`getComputedStyle(document.body).setProperty("--foo", "#4c3552")`

but html does not get updated when applying variable as background color through stylesheet taken that my HTML is `<div id="bar">` and CSS file linked to html has setup like so: `#bar {background-color: var(--foo);}`

Comment: getComputedStyle(document.body) returns a value, not a reference to an element. To get the element, try document.querySelector("#bar").style.setProperty

Comment: @DeeGee Kinda [nope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#return_value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setProperty goes on the Element's `style`.
Read more: [CSSStyleDeclaration setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty)

```js
document.body.style.setProperty("--foo", "red")
```

```css
:root {
  --foo: blue;
}

#bar {
  background-color: var(--foo);
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">TEST</div>
```

Comment: The interesting part of the question is, why setting CSSStyleDeclaration object returned by `getComputedStyle` doesn't work. The answer is, that object represents [read-only interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) (the 3rd item in the first list).